# General error: 1364 Field 'manufacturer_name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I get manufacturer name has no value even tho it references id column in manufacturer table which is already created in database and sits in the same row with manufacturer name. Why is so? Here is code:

Manufacturer table

```php
Schema::create('manufacturer', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->autoIncrement();
    $table->string('manufacturer_name');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Planes table

```
Schema::create('planes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('icao24');
        $table->bigInteger('manufacturer_name')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->foreign('manufacturer_name')->references('id')->on('manufacturer');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Inserting values:

Manufacturer table:

```
$file = fopen('https://opensky-network.org/datasets/metadata/aircraftDatabase.csv', 'r');

        $headersArray = [];
        $i = 0;

        $headers = fgetcsv($file);

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            array_push($headersArray, $value);
        }

        while ($i < 50) {
            $line = fgetcsv($file);

            $comb = array_combine($headersArray, $line);

            DB::table('manufacturer')->insert(array(
                'name' => $comb['manufacturername'],
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')
            )); .....
```

Planes table:

Same loop just different schema:

```
DB::table('planes')->insert(array(
                'icao24' => $comb['icao24'],
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s')
            ));
```

I expect to have incremental ids in plane table inside manufacturer_name column that points to manufacturer name in Manufacturer table. Now it's just all default value 1 in all rows.

Here is how Manufacturer DB looks now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6xLC.png)

I want these ids 2, 3, 4... be inside Planes table as foreign keys in manufacturer name column, but instead now it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyhE3.png)

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` shouldn't be set in your query. They get updated automatically.

Comment: We can't really answer this question without knowing what is in `$comb` and `$line` but where are you *trying* to insert the manufacturer ID? I don't see this anywhere in your code.

Comment: @miken32 They come default when making migration files using artisan. And is it problem related?

Comment: @miken32  putted all the code, you can see I fopen the file as a stream and make an array of values and keys and then use array combine function to merge keys with values and assign it to comb variable. I don’t know why it is unclear for you. Im inserting manufacture id to manufacturer name in this line:

` $table->bigInteger('manufacturer_name')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->foreign('manufacturer_name')->references('id')->on('manufacturer');`

Comment: A migration just builds your database structure. In both comments, I'm talking about the query, where you insert data into the database.

Comment: @miken32 I run them also in seperate migration files. I have create table files and add tables migration files. I know that this should be done in seeds but for now I keep it in migration files. Orders are correct. I also included code for data insertion in OP.

Comment: @miken32 Updated question to make it more clear what my problem is about.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how migrations work. `$table->bigInteger('manufacturer_name')->unsigned()->default(1); $table->foreign('manufacturer_name')->references('id')->on('manufacturer');` is not going to automatically insert data for you. This only tells the database how the tables are related. Your code has to update the columns.

Comment: @ryantxr Can you give me so guidance on how to do it in my case? After I have made manufacturer table with primary key ID and names and populated table with data (50 rows), do I need to retrieve those ids somehow and update my planes table or what? I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @ryantxr When I make tables and insert data in them, if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps.

```
$file = fopen('https://opensky-network.org/datasets/metadata/aircraftDatabase.csv', 'r');

$headersArray = [];
$i = 0;

$headers = fgetcsv($file);

foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
   array_push($headersArray, $value);
}

while ($i < 50) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file);

    $comb = array_combine($headersArray, $line);

    // Look up manuf to see if we already inserted it.
    // Hopefully name isn't duplicated
    $manuf = DB::table('manufacturer')->where('name', $comb['manufacturername'])->first();
    // Only insert if it isn't already there
    if ( ! $manuf ) {
        $manufId = DB::table('manufacturer')->insertGetId(array(
            'name' => $comb['manufacturername'],
        ));
    } else {
        $manufId = $manuf->id;
    }

    DB::table('planes')->insert(array(
        'icao24' => $comb['icao24'],
        'manufacturer_name' => $manufId
    ));

}
```

Migrations and foreign keys

```
Schema::create('planes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->autoIncrement();
    $table->string('icao24');
    $table->bigInteger('manufacturer_name')->unsigned()->default(1); // (1)
    $table->foreign('manufacturer_name')->references('id')->on('manufacturer'); // (2)
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Migrations only describe how to build tables in the database. They don't cause data to be inserted into tables. By defining (1) and (2) above you 
are defining a column and describing how that column relates to another table.

When inserting data into the tables, your code must insert the correct
foreign key values. The migration or the database is not going to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try to update my code with your code but I get ‘call to undefined method stdClass::getKey()’ error? Also you say migrations only describe how to build tables in DB and dont cause data to be inserted. But Iiterally insert data into tables from migration files running artisan migrate and it works fine. You can see from added screenshots that rows are there and they come from migration files, so I don’t really understand what you mean by that. Anyway, if you can give me clues how to fix undefined method error I would be thankful

Comment: Sorry. getKey is an eloquent thing. I replaced it with the correct code.

Comment: Yes, you can put code into migration files that will insert data. What I am saying is that just defining the tables and columns alone will not cause data to be inserted.